# Application performance issue with CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex

Tags: swift, performance, uiimage

I m using `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` to convert the `Data` into `UIImage` , but if I convert around 7-8 image using this method application gets slow, instead of this If I use `UIImage(data:imageData)` everything works fine. How to fix this issue , I need to use `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` to resize the image.
Below is the code I m using.

```
    convenience init?(data: Data, maxSize: CGSize) {
    let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, imageSourceOptions) else {
        return nil
    }

    let options = [
        // The size of the longest edge of the thumbnail
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: max(maxSize.width, maxSize.width),
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
    ] as CFDictionary

    // Generage the thumbnail
    guard let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options) else {
        return nil
    }

    print("Generating Image....")
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when batch processing images. Take a look at your RAM usage, it's off the charts. According to Apple, with CGImageSourceCreateWithData and CGImageSourceCreateWithURL, "You’re responsible for releasing this type using CFRelease."

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/1465073-cgimagesourcecreatewithdata)

With Swift, you can do it using:

```
autoreleasepool {
                                
    let img = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL ...

}
```